# ufw logs BLOCKS from 2 sites while BLOCK logging is completely disabled for ALL sites

Tags: linux, ip, logging

Logging is enabled. Only allow rules are logged.  The very last line of my firewall rules is:

```
Anywhere                   DENY        Anywhere
```

No logging is asked for, however two IPs repeatedly show up in my firewall logs as blocked:

```
Dec 28 16:54:13 openvpn kernel: [1059666.384183] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:3d:09:b4:2c:21:72:a0:20:81:08:00 SRC=216.4.95.62 DST=XXX.XX.XXX.XXX LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=247 ID=57899 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47785 DPT=5555 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0
Dec 28 16:54:13 openvpn kernel: [1059666.665564] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:3d:09:b4:2c:21:72:a0:20:81:08:00 SRC=4.71.37.46 DST=XXX.XX.XXX.XXX LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x40 TTL=244 ID=21110 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33071 DPT=5555 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0
```

Connections are blocked as requested, but why are they logged?  Bothers me when things are unexpected.  All other blocks (there are 1000s) are not logged as requested.  Both addresses are from Level 3's address range.  DPT 5555 is typically the HP Data Protector port (not installed on my server).  Server is hosted on Host Virtual.  Output from uname:

```
Linux XXX.XXX.XXX 5.4.0-91-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 16:31:28 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

All current updates are applied

Adding requested ufw here:
root@openvpn:~# ufw status verbose

Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), allow (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From

---

20/udp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   (log)

22                         ALLOW IN    XXX.XX.XX.0/22             (log)

443/udp                    ALLOW IN    XX.XXX.XXX.0/20            (log)

22                         ALLOW IN    YYY.YYY.YYY.0/22           (log)

443/udp                    ALLOW IN    YYY.YYY.YYY.0/22           (log)

80/udp                     ALLOW IN    WWW.WW.WW.0/22             (log)

80/udp                     ALLOW IN    WWW.WW.WW.0/22             (log)

22                         ALLOW IN    WWW.WW.WW.0/22             (log)

22                         ALLOW IN    XX.XXX.XXX.0/20            (log)

Anywhere                   DENY IN     Anywhere

Comment: Nothing is known about the configuration of the system except your interpretation. Your interpretation might be wrong. Please provide the exact configuration from the time the log messages occured, not only your interpretation.

Comment: OP, in addition to what @SteffenUllrich asked for, please provide the output of `ufw status verbose`

Comment: Too long to add as comment, so edited original post and added sanitized rules from ufw status verbose

Comment: The only logical explanation that I have is that the IPs probing my server have discovered someway to avoid my Anywhere DENY IN Anywhere last rule and hit the default block which is logged.  But how in the world are they avoiding the Anywhere DENY IN Anywhere?  Buffer overflow in the MAC field?

Comment: Last kernel update seems to have fixed.  But, let's leave this open a bit longer to be sure.

Comment: Guess kernel update did not fix:  Jan 12 21:17:23 openvpn kernel: [131856.168424] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:16:3e:3d:09:b4:2c:21:72:a0:20:81:08:00 SRC=138.199.42.130 DST=192.73.242.140 LEN=52 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=29 ID=3567 PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=46140 WINDOW=32182 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0

Comment: This still happens from time to time.  I actually saw this happen and logged from one of my VPN routed networks that are in the allowed rules.  Those entries actually showed the RFC 1918 addresses from those OpenVPN routed networks.  These other log entries first observed from external, public networks.  I wonder now if there could be a compromise on my networks or something odd coming from OpenVPN.